# How can I change the default UI shown by Photon Fusion?

Tags: unity, photon

When I start a Photon Fusion game, I see by default the following dialog box:

[image]

I want to change it, e.g. by removing some options, adding color or text, etc.
I searched for "photon fusion lobby" and "photon fusion change user interface", but did not find any relevant information.

How can I modify this dialog box?

Comment: Just by the available options, I would say this is a debug/ playtesting panel for making your life easier and setting/ testing up your game faster. Usually it is not meant to be modified/ styled but rather that you implement those options yourself as your game needs them.